# What is the meaning of 機歪?

Tags: translation, mandarin, lyrics

I was listening to a Chinese song the other day. The song name is 謝謝妳愛我, sung by R.chord(謝和弦). In the second line of the first chorus, which goes "脾氣壞 固執任性機歪 還有點變態 ", I don't understand the word Ji Wai(機歪) here.

I have looked this word up in many dictionaries but still no luck. However, I have seen someone translating it as "bitchy". Is it correct?

And also, both 固執 and 任性 mean stubborn/headstrong right? Then why use two words with the same meaning?

Here is the link for song lyrics - https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/%E8%AC%9D%E5%92%8C%E5%BC%A6/%E8%AC%9D%E8%AC%9D%E5%A6%B3%E6%84%9B%E6%88%91/translation/english

Comment: [台式國語「機車」是罵人嗎?](http://www.sce.hkbu.edu.hk/media-visitors/our-experts-said/chineselecturer10.php?lang=zh)

Answer (score 8):

機車 and 機歪 are indecent words. As time changes, the meanings are already different. The following is one of them.

The 機歪 refers to the female genitalia - 膣屄 (cunt). The Hokkien pronunciation is tsi-bai.

Because it is too indecent to directly write 膣屄, it has been written as "機掰, 機歪, GY" and so on. Later, some people thought that they were still indecent, so 機車 came out.

The original meaning is lack of being fucked. Because 幹 has the meaning of to beat, it also means lack of being beaten.

However, recently they usually mean very annoying, very picky, not straightforward, indecisive, or doing stupid things depending on the situation.

For instance,

你很機車
can represent
You are very annoying.
You are a real pain in the butt!

## Do not say these words to anyone.

---

固執: adamancy; bigotry; obstinate; stubborn; pigheaded; stick to one's guns and refuse to change

任性: willful; wayward; caprice; self-indulgence; self-will; unruliness

---

---

「機車」和「機歪」是屬於不雅的詞。隨著時間的改變，它的意思已經不太一樣了。底下是其中一種說法。

「機歪」是指女性生殖器——膣屄。閩南語的發音是 tsi-bai。

因為直接寫「膣屄」很不雅，所以被寫成「機掰、機歪、GY」等。後來有人覺得還是不雅，就再演變成「機車」。

原意是「欠幹」。又因為「幹」有「打、揍」的意思，所以也有「欠打、欠揍」的意思。

但是現在這些詞依不同的情況大多表示「很討厭」、「很挑剔」、「不乾脆」、「猶豫不決」、「做了蠢事」。

例如：

你很機車。
可以表示
你很討厭。

## 不要對任何人說這些話。

---

「固執」是「堅持己見，不肯變通」的意思。

「任性」是「放縱性情，恣意而為」的意思。

Comment: Maybe you are talking about "機掰" not "機歪". People from Taiwan refer the word "機掰" to the female genitalia - 膣屄 (cunt). I think "機歪" is "叽歪" in simplified Chinese. Please refer to this site https://hk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071214000051KK03348

Comment: Yeah, I am Hokkien and understand a bit of swear words that my parents use at home lol. Pretty sure Ji Bai refers to "vagina". Not sure if Ji Wai could mean the same. Anyway, thanks a million for your interpretation vuluvsa!

Comment: How did bai become 歪 or Y then?

Answer (score 6):

The word "機歪" (simplified Chinese: 叽歪), means that a person talks too much (probably complaining about something) so that it annoys people around him/her. This is not a formal word that you could find out in a dictionary, and more like a word from spoken language. Besides, another word often used in spoken language is 機機歪歪 (simplified Chinese: 叽叽歪歪) has a similar meaning.

"固執" and "任性" have different meanings. "固執" means stubborn, while "任性" means capricious.

In the song, "固執任性機歪" means 固執，任性，and 機歪.

Comment: Omg! that's a very simple and helpful explanation! Thank you so much :D I understand very well now!

Comment: I think this explanation(answer) is the consensus among the people from the mainland. The other answer might be the explanation from t Taiwan region I guess.